# MySQL SELECT use a selected table as an unique identifier

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble searching for a solution to my problem because I am new to mysql. The following code works:

```
<?php
//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Event.id, Event.type, Event.eventclass, Event.venue,
                       date_format(Event.startdate, '%a %b %e %Y') as sort_startdate,
                       date_format(Event.enddate, '%a %b %e %Y') as sort_enddate,
                       Event.datespecifics, Event.registration,
                       Event.instructor1, Event.instructor2, Event.instructor3,
                       Venue.name, Venue.city
                       FROM Event,Venue
                       Where Event.type = '200HR Teacher Training' AND Event.venue = Venue.id
                       ORDER BY startdate ASC");
//fetch the data from the database
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if(empty($row{instructor2})) {
        echo "<p>At ".$row{name}.", ".$row{city}."<br/>".$row{sort_startdate}." - ".$row{sort_enddate}.", ".$row{datespecifics}."<br/>With: " .$row{instructor1}."</p> <br/><br/>";
    }
    else {
        if(empty($row{instructor3})) {
            echo "<p>At ".$row{name}.", ".$row{city}."<br/>".$row{sort_startdate}." - ".$row{sort_enddate}.", ".$row{datespecifics}."<br/>With ".$row{instructor1}." and ".$row{instructor2}."</p> <br/><br/>";
        }           
        else {
            echo "<p>At ".$row{name}.", ".$row{city}."<br/>".$row{sort_startdate}." - ".$row{sort_enddate}.", ".$row{datespecifics}."<br/>With ".$row{instructor1}.", ".$row{instructor2}." and ".$row{instructor3}."</p> <br/><br/>";
        }       
    }
}
?>
```

The problem is that the output for instructor1, instructor2 and instructor3 is an integer which references another table that lists all instructors. I do not know how to show the instructor's name from that table. I assume that I need to create a variable in the SELECT statement so that I can give each name a unique identifier, but I don't know how to do so. Thank you for your help.

Comment: please be a little more clear

Comment: so basically you run a mysql query then you get a number and then use that number to find all the instructors from another table

Comment: what you need is to normalize your tables not to change your query, as after normalization process you will get rid of this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done with `JOIN` operations. It's a pretty straightforward deal.

You need this:

```
SELECT ...whatever...,
        e1.instructor_name AS instr1, 
        e2.instructor_name AS instr2,
        e3.instructor_name AS instr3,
        Venue.name, Venue.city
  FROM Event
  JOIN Venue ON Event.venue = Venue.id
  LEFT JOIN Instructor AS e1 ON Event.instructor1 = e1.instructor_id
  LEFT JOIN Instructor AS e2 ON Event.instructor2 = e2.instructor_id
  LEFT JOIN Instructor AS e3 ON Event.instructor3 = e3.instructor_id
 Where Event.type = '200HR Teacher Training'
 ORDER BY startdate ASC
```

Notice, because you need to pick up three distinct instructors, you need to JOIN the Instructor table three times, and give it three different aliases `AS e1` etc.

I used LEFT JOIN, because that will still work if you have events that don't have all three instructors.

I'm not sure of the layout (or indeed the name) of your instructor table, so there's some guesswork here.